# MVC anti-forgery token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, antiforgerytoken

I've got a public MVC 5 web-site, using the anti-forgery token. Every day a large number of errors are logged in the form of "The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match.", and a lesser number in the form of "The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.".

The problem is not reproducible, it occurs for different people on different pages at different times. Closing the browser resolves the problem - sometimes just using the Back button and re-trying resolves the problem.

- As the website works for the vast majority of users, I can rule out missing ValidateAntiForgeryToken attributes in controllers, likewise, I can rule out missing or duplicate @Html.AntiForgeryToken() code in the views.
- The website runs on a single server, so I can rule out different machinekeys in the web.config (I've tried running the website with and without this setting anyway).
- The application pool is set to restart each night, and there's plenty of spare resource on the 
  server, so I can rule out the application pool restarting and invalidating sessions (especially as this isn't logged in the event log or anywhere else).
- I've hit the problem very rarely - I definitely have cookies enabled, so I can rule out cookies being disabled. I can also rule out javascript being disabled, as user's can only progress so far into the site without JS - and errors occur on pages beyond this point.
- I've disabled all caching, setting nocache, nostore etc. This seemed to reduce the occurrence of the issue, but it still persisted (I had to re-enable caching for a variety other reasons).

What other options are there to consider?

I am so frustrated by this I am considering turning off anti-forgery protection and contributing to the global weakening of security.

Comment: Is it possible you're posting across domains (wwww to no www; or the opposite) and the cookie isn't surviving the jump?

Comment: All links are generated via the MVC @ helpers, which all inherit the base URL (i.e. unless the MVC framework changes the domain, no).

Comment: have you found a solution already? Just curious.

Comment: Nope, the error is still ongoing.

Comment: I'm having this same issue as well at the moment. Some users have this problem, most do not. Have you gotten any further with it?

Comment: No, still no progress.

Comment: The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the <machineKey> configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Comment: As stated in my question, the website runs on a single server, and I've tried with and without explicit machine keys in the web.config.

Comment: I am facing a very similar issue and have no clue why this is happening. Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have AntiForgery attributes both in controller and forms.

If you are doing ajax post maybe you can send RequestValidationToken as a parameter.

> $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()

Also maybe somebody attacking your site or using some bots to get content or post forms.

Comment: AntiForgery attributes are in the controllers and forms - otherwise surely it would fail for everyone, all the time? The requestverificationtoken is being sent with ajax requests.